# Similarities between Bayes Factor and WAIC formulas?

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, bayes-factors, waic

It looks for me that **WAIC** and **Bayes Factor** are very similar in some circumstances. If we assume an *equal prior* for each parameter set Q (`p(Q)`), the Bayes Factor integrates `p(y|Q)` over the Q space (y is the data), providing the probability of obtaining the data under the model - `p(y)`.

The WAIC formula appears to have a similar calculation, but with the addition of a logarithm (not of interest) and a penalty for likelihood variance. As a result, it seems that, in the case of a flat prior, WAIC is essentially like Bayes but with a penalty.

Is it correct or am I missing something, or maybe messing with it at all?